# How to restore postgreSQL database for odoo to google cloud?

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, odoo, restore

```
$ curl -F 'master_pwd=superadmin_passwd' -F backup_file=https://storage.cloud.google.com/smart02-bucket-1/Smart.zip -F 'copy=true' -F 'name=Smart1' http://34.91.12.120/web/database/
restore
```

After executing this line this is the result

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Session expired (invalid CSRF token)</p>
```

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to restore your Database in Odoo using a backup file that is stored in the Google Cloud Storage? Can you confirm what the file, Smart.zip is? A backup from the PostgreSQL? Is the file publicly available on GCS? I tried to access the file through the GCS link but I get "Not Found", which suggests that the File is not publicly available. And if so, you would not be able to access the file by simply passing the URL into the backup_file flag as the file is privately protected within GCS.

Comment: There are other ways of getting privately protected files from GCS such as using [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)